# Regexp for "either/or" but not "neither"

Tags: regex, notepad++

Working with Notepad++ v7.9 here.

Suppose `R` is a complex regexp pattern. I now want to match `_R`, `R_`, or`_R_` but not `R` alone. How to do this without writing explicitly `(_R|R_|_R_)`? This requires R being written out three times and looks ugly.

The closest I can think of is `_?R_?` but this also matches `R` alone (and is in fact equivalent to it), which is a false positive to me.

In between is `(_?R_|_R_?)` but `R` is repeated again here, though one less time.

Comment: Notepad++ v7.9 in this case. I'll edit.

Comment: Maybe this can help you `(?!^R$)_?R_?`

Comment: I don't have a problem with your current alternation.

Comment: I don't think this is possible but you might find `_?(R)_?\1?_` interesting. https://regex101.com/r/KKNrJa/1

Answer (score 11):

You may use [If-Then-Else](https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) as follows:

```
(_)?R(?(1)_?|_)
```

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/txy0TG/1)**.

This enables you to write `R` only once.

**Breakdown:**

```regex
(_)?        # An optional capturing group that matches an underscore character.
R           # Matches 'R' literally (replace it with your pattern).
(?          # If...
    (1)     # ..the first capturing group is found,...
    _?      # ..then match zero or one underscore characters (optional).
|           # Else (otherwise)...
    _       # Match exactly one underscore character (required).
)           # End If.
```

Works in Notepad++:

[image: Notepad++ demo]

Comment: Wow, I love this. You've introduced me to if/else in regex...

Comment: Did not know about if-Then-Else. Care to explain ?

Comment: @Charles See https://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html.

Comment: I meant, explain this example.

Comment: @Charles Added an explanation. Refer to the first link in my answer for more on how conditional regex works.

Comment: Great, thanks. So the "if" part is basically whether group 1 is empty or not, right ?

Comment: @Charles No, the `if` part triggers if Group 1 is *None*, that is why the `?` is outside of the first capturing group.