# Is it possible to combine two regex patterns into one without using OR | , pipe character

Tags: regex

I am working on regex to match either(not both) of two conditions like this:

1. Digits following A. ex) `A123`, regex `(?<=A)\d+`
2. Digits followed by Z. ex) `123Z`, regex `\d+(?=Z)`

So naive way is to use '|' to combine them like this:

`(?<=A)\d+|\d+(?=Z)`

This could be better for readability and maintainability, but I'm just curious if there is another way to make it without |.

Here is a C# test code for that.

```
            string pattern = @"(?<=A)\d+|\d+(?=Z)";

            var currencies = new string[]{
                "A123", // match
                "123Z", // match
                "123",  // NOT match
            };

            foreach (var c in currencies)
            {
                Match m = Regex.Match(c, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
                Console.WriteLine("Matched:" + m.Success + ". Value:" + m.Value);
            }
```

The output of the code here.

```
Matched:True. Value:123
Matched:True. Value:123
Matched:False. Value:
```

Comment: I can't think of a simpler way to write your regex, and I also don't have any problem with it.

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: Note that your current pattern will match "A123Z", "A123Whatever", and "Whatever123Z".

Comment: Now, to answer your question: no, I don't think there's a cleaner way to write that pattern (i.e., without OR) as others have said. That's because it's already too simple. If the `\d+` part were just a placeholder for something longer (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64680322/8967612), for example), that would've been a different situation. A conditional pattern would be appropriate in that case (see my answer to that question). [1/2]

Comment: With your current situation, however, a conditional pattern would look something like `(?<=(A)?)\d+(?(1)|(?=Z))` (or `(A)?(\d+)(?(1)|Z)` if you're fine with extracting the match from group 2). I think you agree that neither of these look cleaner than your original pattern. Not to mention that you still need some kind of boundaries to avoid the issue described in my first comment. [2/2]